# How to add values ​inside a large array that consists of many objects with maintaining the previous calculations?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Created https://codepen.io/Spawnes/pen/LYmVMJj in which place a large array of data. The task description will be duplicated here:

You need to add the values ​​of `X` with all subsequent `X`

You need to add `Y` values ​​with all subsequent `Y`

You need to add `marker.color` values ​​followed by all `marker.color`

To end up with:

```
1) 1 frame unchanged
2) On the second frame, everything that was in the first + data from the second.
3) On the third frame, the sum of 1 and 2 + new data from the third frame.
4) On the fourth frame, the previous result + data from frame 4
```

And so on

I'll add another screenshot demonstrating the data itself:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiaIU.jpg)

As you can see, there are quite a lot of objects inside. And you just need to make an addition while maintaining the previous calculations.

```
1 + 2 = 3. 

3 + 2 = 5

5 + 6 = 11

11 + 2 = 13
```

Comment: wait do you just need a fibonaci formula or what

Comment: No. 
This is very simple example:

  [1, 5, 10]
  [5, 4, 12]
  [8, 9, 1]
  
  Result
  
  [1, 5, 10]
  [6, 9, 22]
  [14, 18, 23]

Answer (score 0):

Given the complexity of your question this is NOT an answer but a clarification to help you write your question in simpler terms:

So to clarify?

UPDATED:

You want to convert

```js
myArray = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "x": [46,38,71, ....],
                "y": [1,2,3, ....],
            }, {
                "x": [10, 10, 20, ....],
                "y": [100, 500, ....],
            },
            {
                "x": [1, 1, 0, ....],
                "y": [10, 10 ....],
```

to

```js
myArray = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "x": [46,38,71, ....],
                "y": [1,2,3, ....],
            }, {
                "x": [56, 48, 91, ....], // updated (ie 46 + 10 = 56)
                "y": [101, 502, 3 ....], // updated
             }, {
                "x": [57, 49, 91, ....], // updated (ie 56 + 1 = 57)
                "y": [111, 512, 3 ....], // updated
```

My attempted answer based on that

```js
const convertData = obj => {
  const prev = {
    x: [],
    y: []
  }
  return obj.data.map(item => {
    const newX = item.x.map((val, ind) => (
      prev.x[ind] = val + (prev.x[ind] ?? 0)
    ))
    const newY = item.y.map((val, ind) => (
      prev.y[ind] = val + (prev.y[ind] ?? 0)
    ))
    // add other stuff to x or y here accordingly...
    return {x: newX, y: newY}
    
  })
}

const inc = myA => myA.map(obj => convertData(obj))
const myArray = [{
      "data": [
            {
                "x": [46,38,71],
                "y": [1,2,3]
            }, {
                "x": [10, 10, 20],
                "y": [100, 500]
            },
            {
                "x": [1, 1, 0],
                "y": [10, 10]
             }
      ]
 }]
 
 console.log(inc(myArray))
```

Comment: No. I want to add each value of array to all next ones. 
Hope this will help.
  
myArray = [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "x": [1,1,5],
          "y": [1,2,3]

        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "x": [4,6,13],
          "y": [1,2,3]

        }
      ]
    },
  ]

  Result
  
  myArray = [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "x": [1,1,5],
          "y": [1,2,3]

        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "x": [5,7,18],
          "y": [2,4,6]

        }
      ]
    },
  ]

Comment: Yes! :) And, by the way, I have a code for this task already. Updated my codepan. 

But, to be honest, even this is not full task. I have more complicated - there mush be checks for X and Y. And if x AND y are the same with previous  - just add their marker.color. If x or y have some differences - just and this as NEW coordinate. 

I know, it's very hard to explain :(

Comment: I've added a partial solution. You can add additional to it to extend functionality

Answer (score 0):

```js
let firstArr = [1, 5, 10]
let secondArr = [5, 4, 12]
let thirdArr = [8, 9, 1]

const calc = (...args) => {
  let store = []
  return args.map((arr, z) => {
    let newArr =  arr.map((num, i) => {
      if(z > 0){
        return (store[i] + num)
       }
       return num
    })
    
    store = newArr
    return newArr
  })
}

console.log(calc(firstArr, secondArr, thirdArr))
```

Ok taking this as a starting point:  `Result [1, 5, 10] [6, 9, 22] [14, 18, 23]`

The above function does the trick, you have to obviously change it a bit for ur use case specifically, but in general this is what u are looking for.